# What data types are involved in implicit casting in C++?

Tags: c++, casting

Are all primitive data types subject to implicit casting in C++? So for example can I assume that all of the following assignment statements will cause implicit casting because all of the variables involved are primitive data types:

```
intVar = floatVar;
doubleVar = charVar;
unsignedIntVar = boolVar;
```

Or the rules for implicit casting are specified based on a different crietira?

Comment: You can get the compiler to give warnings or even fail for this sort of thing. Best to be explicit

Comment: Take a look at the [article on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast).  (It's really complicated.)

Comment: Casting is never implicit, conversion can be. Casting is explicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Every arithmetic type is implicitly convertible to every other arithmetic type.

If you use gcc or clang, the `-Wconversion` flag may be useful for warning you when such a conversion might narrow. Other compilers probably have similar flags.